# Catastrophe Modeling with Longitude/Latitude coordinates in R

Tags: r, google-maps, coordinates

I've got a pretty interesting question that's giving me a tough time. I work for an insurance company, and we're trying to model our exposure in the event of a terrorist attack.

Here's some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(long=c(-74.01, -73.86, -77.61, -73.99),
             lat=c(40.71,40.94,43.16,40.69),
             limit=c(10,20,30,40))
```

Hypothetical example: a terrorist explodes a bomb at one of our members at coordinates (long=-74.01, lat=40.71). If you don't like that example, pretend it's a natural disaster instead. I'm curious to know what our entire book's exposure is. If the bomb causes $10 million in damage at the one location, how much damage would it cause at our other locations?

Essentially, I want a function in which I can type the name of a city or landmark or pair of coordinates (like the geocode function in ggmap and dismo), and determine our company's exposure. I type in longitude -75, latitude 40, and a bomb or catastrophic event of a certain magnitude, and the function spits out a range of possible losses that our company could suffer.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here... e.g. you haven't told us the relationship between damage at one location and damage at the other locations... or do you just mean that you want to return `limit` for a given pair of coordinates?

Comment: good point. I'll say that every mile away from the center square roots the damage: an event that occurs exactly at the member's address would cause $10 million in damages, while that same event occurring a mile away would cause the square root of $10 million ($3.16 million), and that same event would cause $1.78 million in damages from two miles away.

Comment: My mistake for making the question too broad. Regardless, jbaums' answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do what I think you are trying to do.

```
d <- data.frame(long=c(-74.01, -73.86, -77.61, -73.99),
                lat=c(40.71, 40.94, 43.16, 40.69),
                limit=c(10, 20, 30, 40))

library(sp)
# Coerce d to SpatialPointsDataFrame for ease of distance calculation
coordinates(d) <- ~long+lat

claim <- function(long, lat, damage, member_db) {
  require(sp) # for spDistsN1
  dist_miles <- spDistsN1(member_db, c(long, lat), longlat=TRUE) * 0.62137
  # great circle distance in kilometres, converted to miles
  pmin(member_db$limit, damage^(1/(2^dist_miles)))
  # return member limit, or damage, whichever is lower
}

claim(-75, 40, 15, d)
## [1] 1 1 1 1

claim(-74.01, 40.71, 15, d)
## [1] 10.000000  1.000013  1.000000  2.258128
```

Note that your choice of function, i.e. `cost = damage^(1/2^distance)`, means that the minimum cost per member is 1, since `damage^0` equals 1. (This seems very costly for the insurer!)